# JMeter Kafka test by Pepper-box. Jmeter Error: PlaintTextLoadGenerator: Please make sure... parameters are correctly passed

Tags: apache-kafka, jmeter

I want to do a kafka performmance test by JMeter.
I follow by the next tutorial:

- [tutorial1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-kafka-how-to-load-test-with-jmeter)
- [tutorial2](https://iwconnect.com/testing-kafka-with-jmeter/)

and I got this error:

```
2021-09-01 18:13:04,582 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
2021-09-01 18:13:04,583 INFO o.a.j.s.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: []
2021-09-01 18:13:04,584 INFO o.a.j.p.j.s.JavaSampler: Created class: com.gslab.pepper.sampler.PepperBoxKafkaSampler. Uses tearDownTest: 
2021-09-01 18:13:04,584 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true, *local*)
2021-09-01 18:13:04,733 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group
2021-09-01 18:13:04,733 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group.
2021-09-01 18:13:04,733 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error
2021-09-01 18:13:04,733 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group... number=1 threads=1 ramp-up=1 delayedStart=false
2021-09-01 18:13:04,734 INFO o.a.j.t.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1
2021-09-01 18:13:04,734 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started
2021-09-01 18:13:04,752 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
2021-09-01 18:13:04,757 ERROR c.g.p.l.i.PlaintTextLoadGenerator: Please make sure that expressions functions are already defined and parameters are correctly passed.
com.gslab.pepper.exception.PepperBoxException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.gslab.pepper.input.SchemaTranslator.getPlainTextMsgIterator(SchemaTranslator.java:54) ~[pepper-box-1.0%20(1).jar:?]
    at com.gslab.pepper.input.SchemaProcessor.getPlainTextMessageIterator(SchemaProcessor.java:36) ~[pepper-box-1.0%20(1).jar:?]
    at com.gslab.pepper.loadgen.impl.PlaintTextLoadGenerator.<init>(PlaintTextLoadGenerator.java:34) [pepper-box-1.0%20(1).jar:?]
    at com.gslab.pepper.config.plaintext.PlainTextConfigElement.iterationStart(PlainTextConfigElement.java:53) [pepper-box-1.0%20(1).jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterationStart(GenericController.java:399) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterEvents(GenericController.java:391) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:160) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:134) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.AbstractThreadGroup.next(AbstractThreadGroup.java:91) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:254) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_191]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.gslab.pepper.input.compile.InMemoryJavaCompiler.compileSchemaClass(InMemoryJavaCompiler.java:39) ~[pepper-box-1.0%20(1).jar:?]
    at com.gslab.pepper.input.SchemaTranslator.getPlainTextMsgIterator(SchemaTranslator.java:47) ~[pepper-box-1.0%20(1).jar:?]
... 10 more
2021-09-01 18:13:04,757 ERROR c.g.p.c.p.PlainTextConfigElement: Failed to create PlaintTextLoadGenerator instance
com.gslab.pepper.exception.PepperBoxException: com.gslab.pepper.exception.PepperBoxException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.gslab.pepper.loadgen.impl.PlaintTextLoadGenerator.<init>(PlaintTextLoadGenerator.java:37) ~[pepper-box-1.0%20(1).jar:?]
    at com.gslab.pepper.config.plaintext.PlainTextConfigElement.iterationStart(PlainTextConfigElement.java:53) [pepper-box-1.0%20(1).jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterationStart(GenericController.java:399) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterEvents(GenericController.java:391) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:160) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:134) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.AbstractThreadGroup.next(AbstractThreadGroup.java:91) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:254) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_191]
Caused by: com.gslab.pepper.exception.PepperBoxException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.gslab.pepper.input.SchemaTranslator.getPlainTextMsgIterator(SchemaTranslator.java:54) ~[pepper-box-1.0%20(1).jar:?]
    at com.gslab.pepper.input.SchemaProcessor.getPlainTextMessageIterator(SchemaProcessor.java:36) ~[pepper-box-1.0%20(1).jar:?]
    at com.gslab.pepper.loadgen.impl.PlaintTextLoadGenerator.<init>(PlaintTextLoadGenerator.java:34) ~[pepper-box-1.0%20(1).jar:?]
... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.gslab.pepper.input.compile.InMemoryJavaCompiler.compileSchemaClass(InMemoryJavaCompiler.java:39) ~[pepper-box-1.0%20(1).jar:?]
    at com.gslab.pepper.input.SchemaTranslator.getPlainTextMsgIterator(SchemaTranslator.java:47) ~[pepper-box-1.0%20(1).jar:?]
    at com.gslab.pepper.input.SchemaProcessor.getPlainTextMessageIterator(SchemaProcessor.java:36) ~[pepper-box-1.0%20(1).jar:?]
    at com.gslab.pepper.loadgen.impl.PlaintTextLoadGenerator.<init>(PlaintTextLoadGenerator.java:34) ~[pepper-box-1.0%20(1).jar:?]
... 8 more
2021-09-01 18:13:04,757 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Test failed!
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.gslab.pepper.config.plaintext.PlainTextConfigElement.iterationStart(PlainTextConfigElement.java:63) ~[pepper-box-1.0%20(1).jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterationStart(GenericController.java:399) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterEvents(GenericController.java:391) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:160) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:134) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.AbstractThreadGroup.next(AbstractThreadGroup.java:91) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:254) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_191]
2021-09-01 18:13:04,758 INFO o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
2021-09-01 18:13:04,758 INFO o.a.j.e.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test
2021-09-01 18:13:04,758 INFO o.a.j.g.u.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false, *local*)
```

after I saw this post:
[Jmeter Error: PlaintTextLoadGenerator...](https://github.com/GSLabDev/pepper-box/issues/30)
I installed JDK (win10), but still got the same error, so probably this is the point.

what did I miss?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. You forgot to include the screenshot of your Java Request sampler, it might be the case you're using it in the way which is not supported. Like if you're trying to use JMeter Functions or Variables - it will fail, you will have to go for [template functions](https://github.com/GSLabDev/pepper-box#schema-template-functions) instead (it's possible to [create your own](https://github.com/GSLabDev/pepper-box#custom-functions) if pre-defined ones are not suitable for your case
2. Your  `pepper-box-1.0%20(1).jar` file looks very suspicious, it sounds like you downloaded the plugin to the "lib/ext" folder of your JMeter installation twice, please remove any extra copies as it might cause issues
3. If you have [Kafka java client](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/index.html) libraries in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) you don't need any plugins in order to send a message to Kafka, you can do it using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and this example [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) code:

   ```
   import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer
   import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord

   def props = new Properties();
   props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
   props.put("acks", "all");
   props.put("retries", 0);
   props.put("batch.size", 16384);
   props.put("linger.ms", 1);
   props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
   props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
   props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

   def producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
   producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("your-topic", "your_payload_here");

   producer.close();
   ```